# How to save fragment state in BottomNavView and Navigation in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

**WHY NOT ANY PEOPLE HELP TO ME?**

In my application I used `Navigation component` with `BottomNavigationView` for show some fragments. 
I write below codes, but when change fragment from `BottomNavigationView` recreate fragment! 
I want **save fragment state** and not recreate fragment ! 
**XML codes:**

```
<!--Fragments-->
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/navHost"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_main" />
<!--Bottom nav-->
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_home" />
```

**Activity codes:**

```
private lateinit var navHost: NavHostFragment

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        _binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        navHost = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navHost) as NavHostFragment

        binding.bottomNav.apply {
            setupWithNavController(navHost.navController)
            //Disable double click on item
            setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {}
       }

    override fun onNavigateUp(): Boolean {
       return navHost.navController.navigateUp() || super.onNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

How can I **save state** of **fragments** and not recreate it when click on **BottomNavigationView** items?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can perserve the data https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state or you can also use multiple backstacks https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigation-multiple-back-stacks-6c67ba41952f